# Multiple shapefiles to one GeoPandas GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I'm trying to vertically concatenate multiple shapefiles that reside in one directory, into one geodataframe. They all have the same table schema and same CRS. I am trying to use the code from this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874113/concat-multiple-shapefiles-via-geopandas), but am getting an error 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'split'.

```
from pathlib import Path   
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

folder = Path("shp")

gdf = pd.concat([
    gpd.read_file(shp)
    for shp in folder.glob("*.shp") ## error message points to this line ###
]).pipe(gpd.GeoDataFrame)
```

I'm new to programming and have spent more time than I care to admit trying to figure this one out. I'm open to using alternative Python modules as long as it ends with a geodataframe.

Comment: That's my answer on SO. Try `print(list(shapefiles))`

Comment: Note that `folder.glob("*.shp")` returns and `iterator` and not an `iterable`. The differences is that the `iterator` loads each element lazily and can only be looped through once. So if you're playing around in an interactive session and already consumed the iteration, I'd full expect the error that you're seeing

Comment: @PaulH,  print(list(shapefiles)) does indeed return an empty list

Comment: So that means either: you've consumed the iteration already or your folder path is specified incorrectly

Comment: If you're in an interactive session, it might be "safer" to do: `gdf = pd.concat([gpd.read_file(shp) for shp in folder.glob("*.shp")]).pipe(gpd.GeoDataFrame)`. That way, you'll refresh the iterator each time you run the `concat` command

Comment: side note, you might need add the `axis=1` parameter to `concat`. I can never remember correctly on the first try

Comment: @PaulH I guess my folder path is specified wrong then. I restarted the kernel in my notebook, changed the for loop to include glob, and added axis=1, and get the same error. My notebook resides in the folder above 'shp', and my shapefiles are in the 'shp' folder. Suggestions for fixing the folder variable?

Comment: `/` is your root directory. You probably don't have your data in root. If you have a "shp" folder in your current working directory (notated as `.`), you should use `Path("./shp")` or `Path("shp")`

Comment: @PaulH, ok that makes sense. I changed to each of those and in each case now get the error: AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'split'.  ugh . . .

Comment: Update the question with the line that threw that error. You shouldn't get the from consuming the iterator

Comment: question updated and includes previous suggestions in the comments and the new error msg

Comment: how about a screen shot of your directory structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92634/discussion-between-pdavis-and-paul-h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug a little deeper into the error message and it mentioned something about [fiona](/questions/tagged/fiona). I updated the package and now my script runs. Thanks to [@PaulH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/12552/paul-h) for his [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874113/concat-multiple-shapefiles-via-geopandas) I found on Stack Overflow.